# How to check last running time of any script in linux instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I want to check if my scripts ran the last night(or last ran timestamp) on linux instance based on scripts crontab running time stamp.

So how to get scripts last ran time on linux instance?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest better record the start time during the start of the script and end time at the end of the Script.

```sh
# Start Time Entry
echo "Start : " $(date +%T) > exec.log
start=`date +%s`
 CALL YOUR SCRIPT HERE
 # End Time Entry
end=`date +%s`
echo "End : " $(date +%T) >> exec.log
# Get the Runtime
runtime=$((end-start))
echo "Runtime: $runtime" >> exec.log
```

If there is any better way, I am also curious to see and implement too.

Comment: I have log files to check the same but I was thinking if there is any other way we can check using Linux command

Answer (score 1):

grep cron from your "messages" or "syslog

```
grep -i cron /var/log/messages
```

or create a separate log file for cron from rsyslog, edit file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and change `#cron` to `cron`. You will find logs in `/var/log/cron`